# How to align fabric.Image objects horizontally?

Tags: html5-canvas, fabricjs

I am simply trying to load three rectangular images and want them to align horizontally adjacent to each other.  I thought setting the left property in   `fabric.Image.fromURL` method would accomplish this but the tree images load stacked on top of each other.  Also even though I include  selectable:true, the images are not selectable.  Am I using `fabric.Image.fromURL` incorrectly?

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <!-- Get version 1.1.0 of Fabric.js from CDN -->
        <script src="js/fabric.js"></script>

        <!-- Get the highest 1.X version of jQuery from CDN. Required for ready() function. -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>


            $(function () {

            var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas', {
                backgroundColor: 'black',
                selectionColor: 'blue',
                selectionLineWidth: 0
                // ...
            });
            debugger;
            var tiles = [
            "images/Green.png",
            "images/Red.png",
            "images/Yellow.png"
            ];
            var offset = [
            "0",
            "200",
            "400"
            ];
            debugger;
            for (i = 0; i < tiles.length; i++) {
                fabric.Image.fromURL(tiles[i], function (img) {
                    img.scale(1.0).set({
                        left: offset[i],
                        top: 0,
                        selectable:true,
                    });
                    canvas.add(img).setActiveObject(img);
                });
            }


            function handleDragStart(e) {
                [].forEach.call(images, function (img) {
                    img.classList.remove('img_dragging');
                });
                this.classList.add('img_dragging');
            }

            function handleDragOver(e) {
                if (e.preventDefault) {
                    e.preventDefault(); // Necessary. Allows us to drop.
                }

                e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy'; // See the section on the DataTransfer object.
                // NOTE: comment above refers to the article (see top) -natchiketa

                return false;
            }

            function handleDragEnter(e) {
                // this / e.target is the current hover target.
                this.classList.add('over');
            }

            function handleDragLeave(e) {
                this.classList.remove('over'); // this / e.target is previous target element.
            }

            function handleDrop(e) {
                // this / e.target is current target element.

                if (e.stopPropagation) {
                    e.stopPropagation(); // stops the browser from redirecting.
                }

                var img = document.querySelector('#images img.img_dragging');

                console.log('event: ', e);

                var newImage = new fabric.Image(img, {
                    width: img.width,
                    height: img.height,
                    // Set the center of the new object based on the event coordinates relative
                    // to the canvas container.
                    left: e.layerX,
                    top: e.layerY
                });
                canvas.add(newImage);

                return false;
            }

            function handleDragEnd(e) {
                // this/e.target is the source node.
                [].forEach.call(images, function (img) {
                    img.classList.remove('img_dragging');
                });
            }



                // Bind the event listeners for the image elements
                var images = document.querySelectorAll('#images img');
                [].forEach.call(images, function (img) {
                    img.addEventListener('dragstart', handleDragStart, false);
                    img.addEventListener('dragend', handleDragEnd, false);
                });
                // Bind the event listeners for the canvas
                var canvasContainer = document.getElementById('canvas-container');
                canvasContainer.addEventListener('dragenter', handleDragEnter, false);
                canvasContainer.addEventListener('dragover', handleDragOver, false);
                canvasContainer.addEventListener('dragleave', handleDragLeave, false);
                canvasContainer.addEventListener('drop', handleDrop, false);


            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>



        <div id="canvas-container">
            <canvas id="canvas"  width="600" height="200"></canvas>
        </div>
        <div id="images">
            <img draggable="true" src="images/Red.png" width="50" height="50"></img>
            <img draggable="true" src="images/Yellow.png" width="50" height="50"></img>
            <img draggable="true" src="images/Green.png" width="50" height="50"></img>
        </div>



    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a race condition between your `fabric.Image.fromURL` callback and the execution of the `for` loop, which prevents the images from showing.

If you print `i` and `offset[i]` inside your callback:

```
fabric.Image.fromURL(tiles[i], function (img) {
    console.log(i, offset[i]);
    ...                
});
```

you'll notice that `i` is `3` and `offset[i]` is `undefined` in all off the callbacks.

This happens because each of the callbacks retain a reference to the same instance of the `i` variable, and use its latest value at the time they execute. The for loop loops through its cycles, each time incrementing `i`, before any of your callbacks execute, leaving `i` with a final value of `3`. When your callbacks execute, they try to set the `left:` value to `offset[3]`, which is undefined, and fabric falls back to `0`.

**Solution**

Variables in pre-ES6 javascript (unlike most languages) are only scoped to the function they are declared it, and code-blocks do not affect scope.

Place your image build logic into its own function, passing the current value of `i` as a parameter in each loop cycle. This will place the value into a new scope, and preserve the value.

Also, don't forget the `var` keyword in front of your `i`. Otherwise you're affecting the global namespace, which you want to avoid at all cost.

Here's what your code should look like:

```
for (var i = 0; i < tiles.length; i++) {
    buildImage(i);
}

// creates a new scope for the passed in value of i when called:
function buildImage(i) {
    fabric.Image.fromURL(tiles[i], function (img) {
        img.scale(1.0).set({
            left: offset[i],
            top: 0,
            selectable: true,
        });
        canvas.add(img).setActiveObject(img);
    });
}
```

Finally, you may want to consider setting the [`originX`](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html#originX) and [`originY`](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html#originY) properties of the images, like so:

```
originX: 'left',
originY: 'top'
```

By default, fabric will use the center of the images as the point of origin when placing them, and your images will not be in full view of the canvas.

**Update**

Here is the [fully working example](https://gist.github.com/stiliyan/72135f1867bc363a75af). It is dependent on fabric, which needs to be placed in your js/ folder.

Comment: Actually this doesn't work.  Now it load no images at all (using the exact code above).  Still I'm certain you are right that it is a race condition I'm just not sure how to debug or solve it.

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in your JavaScript console?

Comment: Just added a full gist which should help. I'm using placeholder.it images to create the squares, but you can easily replace the paths with images/*.png as in your question.